# Robots.txt file

Tags: robots.txt

I am using this code in my robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: *

Disallow:
```

But, my one competitor is using

```
User-agent: *

Disallow: /
```

And his site is performing well in Google and on 1st rank. But my site is not ranking. I have checked everything in my site and it is OK. But how my competitor is performing well in Google? Is robots.txt file doesn't matter?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: Is this the *whole* content of your competitor’s robots.txt file?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an SEO question outside [the scope defined by the SEO tag wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/seo/info). It might be on-topic for [the webmasters stackexchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 9):

Your site ranking is not depended on your `robots.txt` file. You just tell google how to crawl and index pages on your website.

Web site owners use the `/robots.txt` file to give instructions about their site to web robots;

Your site ranking depends on many factors like:

- Keyword usage
- Site structure
- Site speed
- Time spent on site
- Number of inbound links
- Quality of inbound links

---

By the way this will block all web crawlers from all content:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

And this will allow all crawlers to access everything:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

Answer (score 1):

Please follow as below steps.

1)

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Add which page or direct you don't want to crawl if you're targeting main director add public/domain name in it for disallow all

2)our site ranking depends on many factors like: <- This thing also matters nice wrote.

```
Keyword usage
Site structure
Site speed
Time spent on site
Number of inbound links
Quality of inbound links
```

3)take a help for website source http://www.robotsgenerator.com/

P.S. :- please remove website owner marketing link in robots.txt file for sure.