# What does this robot.txt mean?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, robots.txt

There's a website that I need to crawl, I have no financial purpose just to study.

I checked the `robots.txt` and it was as follows.

```
User-agent: *

Allow: /

Disallow: /*.notfound.html
```

Can I crawl this website using `request` and `beautifulSoup`?

I checked that crawling without a header causes a 403 error. Does this mean that crawling is not allowed?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30681245/robots-txt-file/30681275#:~:text=Web%20site%20owners%20use%20the,Site%20structure) might help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

status code: 403 means client-side error and from the server-side such type of
error is not responsible  for  meaning the website is allowed to extract data. To get ride of 403 error you must need to inject something with requests like headers and most of the time but not always  will solve this problem just injecting `User-Agent` as header. Here is an example how to inject User-Agent using `requests` module with `BeautifulSoup`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

header = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"
}

response = requests.get("Your url", headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)

#soup = BeautifulSoup(response .content, "lxml")
```

Comment: Thanks to you, i solve the problem using a header! I have one more question. I'm going to crawl repeatedly(every minute) and wouldn't it be considered a server attack?